# installed npm via nvm, the "node" directory is present but say no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm

Im in an Alpine dev container

> vscode ➜ ~/.nvm (0ccd099) $ nvm which 14
>
> /home/vscode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/bin/node
>
> vscode ➜ ~/.nvm (0ccd099) $ npm
>
> env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

ive got this in my .bashrc as suggested, the dir is in the path

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

also shows I got node installed:

> vscode ➜ ~/.nvm (0ccd099) $ nvm exec 14 node --version
> Running node v14.20.1 (npm v)
> /home/vscode/.nvm/nvm-exec: line 15:/home/vscode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/bin/node: No such file or directory

update:

> vscode ➜ /workspaces/igo2-lib $ ls
> /home/vscode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/bin/ & which node [1] 19986
> /home/vscode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/bin/node corepack  node  npm
> npx [1]+  Done                    ls
> /home/vscode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/bin/

what should I do to get npm working

Comment: update question with these cmds output. `ls /home/vscode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/bin/` & `which node`

Comment: vscode ➜ /workspaces/igo2-lib $ ls /home/vscode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/bin/ & which node
[1] 19986
/home/vscode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/bin/node
corepack  node  npm  npx
[1]+  Done                    ls /home/vscode/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.1/bin/

Comment: its installed, so run `nvm use 14` after that run `node -v`.

Comment: this is what I get env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

Comment: Ive switched to Ubuntu but Im keen on understanding this phenomenon